How to Get Drag Control's Coordinate in Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Custom?
A avalonia Project,to Drag a control and need to Save the Coordinate,so binding to Left and Top in ViewModel 。but when draged,ViewModel never change when Control is Dragged.
use Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Custom.
Front end like this:
<UserControl x:Class="BehaviorsTestApplication.Views.Pages.CustomBehaviorView"
             xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity"
             xmlns:iac="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Custom;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Custom"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="using:BehaviorsTestApplication.ViewModels"
             x:CompileBindings="True" x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="450">
  <Design.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
  </Design.DataContext>
   <DockPanel>
    <Canvas>
      <Image Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" IsHitTestVisible="True" 
        Source="resm:Avalonia.Skia.Assets.NoiseAsset_256X256_PNG.png?assembly=Avalonia.Skia" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <iac:DragControlBehavior  />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      </Image>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Left }" Canvas.Top="200" />
    </Canvas>
  </DockPanel>
</UserControl>


and ViewModel
  private double _left=60;
 public double Left
  {
      get=>_left;
      set=>this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _left,value);
  }

When Drag the Control,is there any way to get Canvas Coordinate? than you
